# tsParticles: Disable audio in fireworks preset

Tags: javascript, typescript, audio, configuration, particles

I am using the [tsParticles firework preset](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles#fireworks) but I don't want any sound effects nor the audio controls that appear at the upper-right.

The fireworks preset comes with an option to disable sound, but it does not appear to do anything.

How do I disable the sound effects and hide the audio controls?

Here is what I am doing:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="tsparticles"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles-preset-fireworks@2/tsparticles.preset.fireworks.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      (async () => {
        await tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
          sounds: {
            enable: false,
          },
          preset: "fireworks",
        });
      })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug. It should've worked, but it's fixed in 2.9.3 released today

Comment: Will this prevent tsparticles loading the .mp3 files as well ?

Comment: Yes, it also prevents the mp3 files from loading.